# How to make panel fit parent in card layout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a `JFrame` with `CardLayout` that contains 2 `JTappedPane` components and 2 `JPanel` and a side panel with buttons to control switching between panels in the card layout, my problem is when I switch between panels the size of the window changes and shows gaps and I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) The side panel should be added to the "LINE_START" of the BorderLayout of your frame. 2) A panel with a CardLayout should be added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of your frame 3) then you add each panel to the card layout when you create the frame. Each of these child panels will fill the remaining space available available to the frame. The layout of the components on each panel will depend on the layout managers that you use.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: this code was generated automatically with the design tab in netbeans without any code modifications, can you please show how to do this in design mode. @camickr

Comment: I don't use an IDE to generate the layout code. You spend time learning the IDE and not learning how to use Java/Swing. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples of how to write your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that by setting both the `minimum size` and the `preferred size` of my `jPanels` and `jTappedPanes` to the exact size of the parent `card layout` and unchecked the `horizontal resizing` and `vertical resizing` for each one of them.